# Member assignment and ref counting in __init__

Tags: python, python-c-api

I'm writing a C extension for Python and going through the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/extending/newtypes_tutorial.html#adding-data-and-methods-to-the-basic-example), I'm having a hard time understanding member assignment in the `__init__` function.

So there, in section 2.2, member assignment is done as follow:

```
if (first) {
    tmp = self->first;
    Py_INCREF(first);
    self->first = first;
    Py_XDECREF(tmp);
}
```

The explanation says later:

> Our type doesn’t restrict the type of the first member, so it could be any kind of object. It could have a destructor that causes code to be executed that tries to access the first member; or that destructor could release the Global interpreter Lock and let arbitrary code run in other threads that accesses and modifies our object.

If I `Py_XDECREF` it, `self->first` will become invalid.

I understand the case where, if the destructor releases the Global interpreter Lock, there is a dangling pointer and my object (`self`) could be modified, etc... Everything goes out of control.

But why is it an issue the destructor accesses it ? Why this part:

> It could have a destructor that causes code to be executed that tries to access the first member;

is an issue ? If the destructor of `self->first` accesses itself, fine. I don't care, it's its problem.

Hope I'm clear enough. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: not quite sure where the confusion is, but maybe here: the object referred to by `first` could have a reference back to the object being initialised, this other object's destructor could itself change `first` (it's exposed via a `PyMemberDef`) and cause an issue, if the code wasn't being as careful.  can write up a better description as an answer if that's about right...

Comment: Did not think about the back reference problem. Thanks for pointing it out @SamMason
However, in such a situation, why on hell would the destructor of `first` do something with the back reference (the `self` of `self->first`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you allow arbitrary Python code to run you need to make sure your object is in a valid state.

When you `DECREF` an object it's possible that arbitrary Python code is run, for example if the object being deleted has a `__del__` method (or if it's a C extension method a `tp_dealloc`). That code could do anything, for example (like mentioned in the quoted text) access the `first` attribute of the instance.

For example:

```
c = Custom("Firstname", "Lastname", 10)

class T:
    def __del__(self):
        print("T", c.first)  # access the first attribute of the "c" variable

c.first = T()
c.__init__(T())
c.__init__(T())
c.__init__(T())
```

Now if your C code would look like this:

```c
Py_XDECREF(self->first);
Py_INCREF(first);
self->first = first;
```

At the time the `T.__del__` would run (triggered by `Py_XDECREF`) it would access the `c.first` which at that moment is an invalid object (because it has a reference count of `0`).

In this example it *accidentally doesn't break* (on my computer) because the memory isn't re-used yet. However if it's slightly more complex it *often kills the Python process* (on my computer):

```py
c = Custom("Firstname", "Lastname", 10)

class T:
    def __del__(self):
        print("T", c.first)

class U:
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.t = t

    def __del__(self):
        print("U")

c.first = U(T())
c.__init__(U(T()))  # repeated multiple times to make the crash more likely
c.__init__(U(T()))
c.__init__(U(T()))
```

---

All that can be avoided (and should be avoided) by making sure the object is in a valid state *before* calling `DECREF` (not just during `__init__` but everywhere!), either by setting it to `null`:

```c
Py_CLEAR(self->first);  // Sets the field to null before XDECREF is used
Py_INCREF(first);
self->first = first;
```

Or by replacing it immediately with `first`:

```c
tmp = self->first;
Py_INCREF(first);
self->first = first;
Py_XDECREF(tmp);
```

Or if you don't want to repeatedly use this kind of idiom, you can also create a function like this:

```c
static void replace_field(PyObject **field, PyObject *val)
{
    PyObject *tmp = *field;
    *field = val;
    Py_XDECREF(tmp);
}
```

Which simplifies the code to:

```c
Py_INCREF(first);
replace_field(&self->first, first);
```

Comment: As I always pay attention to what I'm doing in `__del__`, I did not think about such (evil) possibilities.
Thanks for the `Py_CLEAR` macro, did not see it at first in the doc. ;)